# How to get value from an Object?

Tags: php, symfony, object, symfony-4.2

I am working on Symfony 4.2, 
I fetched the session in my controller like:

> $data = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

when I

> dump($data);

gives me,

```
DashboardController.php on line 17:
User {#504 ▼
  -id: 1
  -f_name: "Kumar"
  -l_name: "Saurabh"
  -username: "supa-admin"
  -password: "$2y$12$qerXOggk6RdKjoE1J4R5I.OzvSYuGdq6E.m1bZp.cPMxolCd/F1xm"
  -email: "some_email@gmail.com"
  -address: Address {#525 ▶}
  -contact: 78954
  -gender: "male"
  -age: 26
}
```

Here, **How can I get 'f_name'** from this object?

Comment: $data->f_name try this

Comment: Is the `User` class created by yourself, or is it part of a library? If you created it yourself, you could add a `getFName()` method. Otherwise you have to look in the class or its documentation, a similar method probably exists.

Comment: @AjayNamdev: I have tried this at very begining, it give error 'Cannot access private property App\Entity\User::$f_name'

Comment: @AnthonyB: thanks mate, I got the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you need to create setters and getters within your User model/entity. Or you could create a __get() / __set() function within the same model / entity to get this information.